# Some specials have no campaign details associated to it

Tags: foursquare

A number of my specials have no campaign details associated to it. However, to be able to post a page update in Foursquare it requires a campaign Id, therefore I am no longer able to post a page update with a special attached.

My Special ID is 50ab336490e745590ae17e57 and that I can pull its details via API call. But when retrieving list of all campaigns, the special doesn't exist/not associated to any campaign.

And Add a page update requires CampaignID
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/pageupdates/add

Has there been a change in Foursquare API? Thanks, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are making the request to the campaigns/list and specials/detail endpoint with the same user who created the campaign and special. This information is only available to the manager of the special.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing just that. I'm also the manager of the special. But I still cannot see. Thanks!

Comment: If you're still having trouble you should send your user information and the special you are trying to administer to api@foursquare.com so it can be debugged.